# Getting the start address of the current process's heap?

Tags: pointers, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory, low-level

I am exploring the lower level workings of the system, and was wondering how `malloc` determines the start address of the heap. Is the heap at a constant offset or is there a call of some sort to get the start address? Does the stack affect the start address of the heap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditionally, the heap started just above the text section and grew up; stack frames didn't affect start address at all as they grow down towards the unmapped 0 page. However, it's more common these days for

1. The first address to be randomized, to make it harder for exploits to hit the right address in memory
2. The heap to be non-contiguous, as `malloc()` usually just calls `mmap()` to get an address anywhere in the virtual address space

Comment: The statically initialized `.data` section isn't usually considered part of the heap, I thought. 
 In traditional Unix (including modern Linux), `.bss` is right above `.data`, basically the allocation is longer than the part of the executable backing it, so you have some zeros to use as the BSS.  The end of *that* area (the BSS) is the "break", and a `brk` system call can increase (or decrease) the address of that boundary, allocating or deallocating heap memory.  So the heap starts after the highest address in the BSS.  (glibc malloc uses brk for small allocations, but mmap for large ones)

Answer (score 4):

*sbrk* returns the start address of the bytes it adds (or removes). In a fresh process with no heap allocated yet, the first call to *sbrk* should then return the start address of the "break" section of the heap. If I had to bet, that's what *malloc* implementations which use *brk/sbrk* probably do on their first run.